# Nuke/Delete/Truncate Database entries after each test WITHOUT the use of data fixtures

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony-3.4

I have the following test cases:

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use AppBundle\Entity\ContactEmail;

class ContactEmailTest extends KernelTestCase
{
  /**
    * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    */
   private $entityManager;

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   protected function setUp()
   {
       $kernel = self::bootKernel();

       $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
           ->get('doctrine')
           ->getManager();
   }


   public function testInsert()
   {
     $email="jdoe@example.com";
     /**
     * @var Appbundle\Repository\ContactEmailRepository
     */
     $repository=$this->entityManager->getRepository(ContactEmail::class);

     $contactEmailEntity=$repository->addEmail($email);
     $this->assertEquals($contactEmailEntity->getEmail(),$email);

     $emailSearched=$repository->findByEmail($email);

     if(empty($emailSearched)){
        $this->fail('No email has been found');
     }

     $this->assertEquals($email,$emailSearched[0]);
   }


   /**
   * expectException(Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException)
   */
   public function testInsertDucplicate()
   {
     $email="jdoe@example.com";
     /**
     * @var Appbundle\Repository\ContactEmailRepository
     */
     $repository=$this->entityManager->getRepository(ContactEmail::class);

     // We purpocely ingoring the returned value
     $repository->addEmail($email);
     $repository->addEmail($email);

   }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->entityManager->close();
        $this->entityManager = null; // avoid memory leaks
    }
}
```

Where I try to test the following method of a custom repository:

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\ContactEmail;

/**
 * ContactEmailRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class ContactEmailRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
  /**
  * Adding an Email to the database
  * @param String $email
  *
  * @throws Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException
  *
  * @return AppBundle\Entity\ContactEmail
  */
  public function addEmail($email)
  {
      $emailToAdd=new ContactEmail();
      $emailToAdd->setEmail($email);

      /**
      * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
      */
      $em=$this->getEntityManager();

      $em->persist($emailToAdd);
      $em->flush();

      return $emailToAdd;
  }
}
```

So how after each test I will nuke all the database entries, in order to have a fresh empty database with a clean instance?

The reason why I am asking is because I do not want to have leftover entries from previous tests where may ruin my tests.

Comment: Maybe I missed something in your code that should make it more obvious to me, but I'm curious why you are wanting to avoid using data fixtures?

Comment: I am not avoiding it is just in my test case I do not need data fixtures. If you look it more closely you will see that I test the data insertion, Therefore there is no need for data fixtures. I just put the data fixture reference in order to distinguish my question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449639/teardown-database-after-a-phpunittest-on-a-webtestcase-using-datafixtures) one.

Comment: You could reset  the database on `setUp()` or `tearDown()` or both. E.g. have a snapshot file-system resetting the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good what to do that is to use logic mentioned on an [answer to "TearDown database after a phpUnitTest on a WebTestCase using DataFixtures"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51462529/4706711) in this network. In order to do that change the `setUp` method into:

```
   //namespace definition and use classes from other namespaces

   use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

   //Class definition etc etc...

   protected function setUp()
   {
       $kernel = self::bootKernel();

       $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
           ->get('doctrine')
           ->getManager();

       //In case leftover entries exist
       $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($this->entityManager);
       $metadata = $this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();

       // Drop and recreate tables for all entities
       $schemaTool->dropSchema($metadata);
       $schemaTool->createSchema($metadata);
   }
```

As you can see you get the schema infomration via the `$this->entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();` chain method call and then you use the chematool to purge and create programmatically the schema.

Also a good way is to have seperate database for tests in my case I put the following configuration into the `config-test.yml`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      dbname: '%database_name%-test'
```

That automatically adds a `-test` ending to the database name so if my database where I do the development is named `mydb` the test database will be `mydb-test` so you can perform your tests as you please without worrying wrecking the development workflow.